# get the date format on a Matplotlib plot's x-axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I generate a plot using the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

index=pd.date_range('2018-01-01',periods=200)
data=pd.Series(np.random.randn(200),index=index)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(data)
```

Which gives me a plot, looking as follows:

[image: Random timeseries]

It looks like Matplotlib has decided to format the x-ticks as `%Y-%m` ([source](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior))

I am looking for a way to retrieve this date format. A function like `ax.get_xtickformat()`, which would then return `%Y-%m`. Which is the smartest way to do this?

Comment: Do you want to modify the dateformat, or get it? The current `x-ticks` is `%Y-%m`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in way to obtain the date format used to label the axes. The reason is that this format is determined at drawtime and may even change as you zoom in or out of the plot.

However you may still determine the format yourself. This requires to draw the figure first, such that the ticklocations are fixed. Then you may query the formats used in the automatic formatting and select the one which would be chosen for the current view.

Note that the following assumes that an `AutoDateFormatter` or a formatter subclassing this is in use (which should be the case by default).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

index=pd.date_range('2018-01-01',periods=200)
data=pd.Series(np.random.randn(200),index=index)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(data)

def get_fmt(axis):
    axis.axes.figure.canvas.draw()
    formatter = axis.get_major_formatter()
    locator_unit_scale = float(formatter._locator._get_unit())       
    fmt = next((fmt for scale, fmt in sorted(formatter.scaled.items())
                if scale >= locator_unit_scale),
                       formatter.defaultfmt)
    return fmt

print(get_fmt(plt.gca().xaxis))
plt.show()
```

This prints `%Y-%m`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to edit the format of the date in `myFmt = DateFormatter("%d-%m-%Y")`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter

index=pd.date_range('2018-01-01',periods=200)
data=pd.Series(np.random.randn(200),index=index)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(index, data)

myFmt = DateFormatter("%d-%m-%Y")
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)
fig.autofmt_xdate()

plt.show()
```

Comment: Not really. I want to keep the dateformat as whatever Matplotlib comes up with (`%Y-%d` in this case) . I just want to know what it came up with...

Comment: OK, i see. but I think in this case is `%Y-%m`

Comment: Right. Thx. Edited :)